# Forward a call in Twilio with a greeting to the called party

Tags: twilio

I have a Twilio app that receives calls from a Caller and forwards them to a Recipient based on attributes of the incoming call.  When calling the recipient, I would like to play a greeting message before making the calls - is there a way to do this?

My TwiML response currently looks something like this:

```
<Response>
    <Dial number="+18005551212"/>
</Response>
```

I would like to do something like this, but don't know how:

```
<Response>
    <Dial>
        <Number>+18005551212</Number>
        <SayToRecipient>This is AwesomeApp. I am forwarding a call from 301-555-1212. BEEP.</SayToRecipient>
        <NowConnectTheCalls/>
    </Dial>
</Response>
```

**Is there away to do this?**

Answer (score 2):

Twilio evangelist here.

Yup.  What you want to do is called a whisper and we have a How To that shows you how to build this:

https://www.twilio.com/docs/howto/ivrs-call-screening-and-recording

The short version is that the `<Number>` noun has a URL attribute that allows you to pass TwiML to Twilio that we will execute when the dialed party answers but before the two calls are connected.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Amazing.  Thanks for the pointer.  Twist:  what if I wanted to say the custom message for the Recipient after the calls are connected?  (1) I get an incoming call from Caller, (2) I forward by Dialing to Recipient, (3) Caller hangs up, (4) I continue my interaction with the Recipient.  Is that possible?

Comment: Thats a bit more complex because once Caller hangs up twilio will also hangup the Recipient.  To prevent that you'll need to use a conference.  Caller calls in, put them into a conference.  Use the REST API to make an outbound call to Recipient, play your message then put them into the same conference.  When Caller hangs up, redirect Recipients call out of the conference to your message.