# How to know when a call is forwarded from Twilio?

Tags: twilio, twilio-programmable-voice

I have a (UK Landline) phone number at Twilio.  I have set up call forwarding, so that the caller ID `{{contact.channel.address}}` is passed on to me (using Twilio studio).

I want to know when the call has been forwarded to me so that I can disambiguate from other calls. But, I also want to keep the original caller ID (if possible).

Is there a way to either:

- Play a short audio message only to me before the caller connects, or
- Somehow flag that the call was forwarded from a specific number,
  and display that on my phone (iPhone on EE uk).

Answer (score 1):

I found some pointers in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28153326/forward-a-call-in-twilio-with-a-greeting-to-the-called-party) and [here](https://www.twilio.com/docs/glossary/call-whisper), and it's a called a "Whisper".

The simplest way to do this is to create two "Twiml Bins".

Bin 1 - `Call Whisper` to just `<Say>` a message

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response>
    <Say>Forwarded from Twilio!</Say>
</Response>
```

Bin 2 - `Call forward and whisper` to forward the call, but execute the whisper `Twiml` (above) before connecting the caller:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response>
    <Dial>
         <Number url="https://handler.twilio.com/twiml/{yourtwiliobinabove}">
            44xxxxxx(your number)
        </Number>  
    </Dial>
</Response>
```